# How to avoid parsley.js to move form elements from horizontal to vertical?

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I want parsley to keep the form's horizontal layout like the one below:
[without including parsley](http://s28.postimg.org/s47lb6pr1/without.jpg)
but whenever I include parsley into the  form:
    `<form name="example_form" data-parsley-validate>` it changes to this:
[with parsley included](http://s23.postimg.org/eyscqdv9n/with.jpg)
How can i keep the original format?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsley adds empty `<ul class="parsley-errors-list">` that would contain validation errors. See the `errorsWrapper` setting. By default, `<ul>` have a display set to `block`.

Tweak your CSS so it fits your needs, and think about how you'd like validation errors to show...

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm kind of making my way out!